# Nested Select with JOIN, Returns NULL if no match?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a problem with MySQL joins, the join condition is occasionally not fulfilled in the first nested Select query and this results in a complete NULL result from this query.

Can someone enlighten me what exactly is going on? I intend to get a value out of the query regardless if the conditions of the join statement in met in the first nested select query.

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM 
        package_orders
        JOIN packages_products 
        ON package_orders.package_id = package_orders.package_id
    WHERE 
        quote_id =1
    AND rev =1
)
+
(
    SELECT SUM(amount) 
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE 
        quote_id =1
    AND rev =1
) 
AS quote_total
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried `left join`?

Comment: a left join returns a NULL value too unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two potential problems.

If your question is simply that joining from package_orders on packages_products returns null, are you possibly looking for an outer join?  An outer join would return package_orders even if there wasn't a matching package_products.

```
SELECT (
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM package_orders
LEFT JOIN packages_products ON package_orders.package_id = package_orders.package_id
WHERE quote_id =1
AND rev =1
...
```

Or is your problem that the second value query

```
...
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM orders
WHERE quote_id =1
AND rev =1
...
```

causes the entire thing to be null?  This would be because a number + null = null.  So if this second query may return null, you need to handle that case and return zero.

```
...
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM orders
WHERE quote_id =1
AND rev =1), 0)
...
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey really appreciate this! Only learned about NULL+1 = NULL today.
And yes having fixed the first SELECT query, the 2nd one becomes a problem when there are no orders made - resulting in a NULL value even if there were packages! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

`NULL+1` is still `NULL`, so you have to wrap the first `SELECT` with `IFNULL(expr1, 0)` like so:

```
SELECT IFNULL((
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM package_orders
JOIN packages_products ON package_orders.package_id = package_orders.package_id
WHERE quote_id =1
AND rev =1
),0)

+

(
SELECT SUM(amount) 
FROM orders
WHERE quote_id =1
AND rev =1
) 

AS quote_total
```